# Comparing two subqueries

Tags: sql-server, case

I would ask my database: does second subquery contain result of first subquery.

Example:

```
select 
    case
        when (select [sub1_column] from [sub1]) IN (select [sub2_column] from [sub2]) then 'true' 
        else 'false'
    end;
```

This code failed with:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

How to compare these subqueries?

EDIT:

My tables look like this:

```
[sub1_column]|
-------------+
|    'd'     |
|    'c'     |
|    'b'     |
-------------+

[sub2_column]|
-------------+
|    'a'     |
|    'b'     |
|    'c'     |
|    'd'     |
|    'e'     |
-------------+
```

The result is TRUE sub_1column values are in sub2_column

`CASE` statement was only an example. What if I would like to compare these subqueries in `WHERE` statement?

Comment: Please check my answer with `EXCEPT` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Use `EXCEPT`. If no records found, both have same records. If records found, records mismatched.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                [sub1_column]
            FROM
                [sub1]
            EXCEPT
            SELECT
                [sub2_column]
            FROM
                [sub2]
        )           
        THEN 'true' 
        ELSE 'false'
    END;
```

Comment: Ok I finally made it with your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.sub1 WHERE sub1_column IN(select sub2_column from sub2)
)
THEN 'true'
ELSE 'false' END AS Sub1ColumnExistsInSub2Column
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ec1c6/2/0)</kbd> with your sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28INTERSECT_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true) to get records which exists in both queries:

```
select 
case
    when exists(
            select [sub1_column] from [sub1]
            intersect
            select [sub2_column] from [sub2]
           )
     then 'true' 
     else 'false'
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
select sub1_column,
       CASE WHEN sub2_column IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS sub2_column
from sub1 LEFT JOIN
     sub2 on sub1.sub1_column=sub2.sub2_column
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a join?

```
select ...
from (select [sub1_column] from [sub1]) as a
join (select [sub2_column] from [sub2]) as b on a.[sub1_column] = b.[sub2_column]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your two tables, and make sure that there are no rows on the second set that are not in the first set.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sub1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN sub2 ON sub1.sub1_column=sub2.sub2_column
WHERE sub2.sub2_column IS NULL
```

This will efficiently return >0 if all the sub1 column values are all included in sub2, and 0 otherwise.
You can easily extend this to EXISTS() or CASE if you need (WHEN 0 ELSE...)